# Replace entire columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I would like to replace entire columns of a pandas dataframe with other columns, for example:

[image]

and I would like to replace the columns A and B. What I did is the following:

```
df['A']=dataFrame['opcodes'].values
df['B']=dataFrame['opt'].values
```

or also

```
df['A']=dataFrame['opcodes']
df['B']=dataFrame['opt']
```

but it does not work. In particular I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'opcodes'
```

in both cases. Can anyone help me? Thank's in advance.

[EDIT] The original dataframe is the following:

[image]

on which I did the following modification:

```
dataFrame['opcodes'] = dataFrame['instructions'].apply(lambda x:[i.split()  [0] for i in x])
```

now I would like to define an other dataframe on which only the 'opt' column and a column with the values 'opcodes' appear.

Comment: See my edit below for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a KeyError because `'opcodes'` doesn't exist in `dataFrame`. Can you show us the contents of `dataFrame` not just `df`?

EDIT:

You don't need to create an empty DataFrame and then apply the data across. Simply do:

```py
df = dataFrame[["opt", "opcodes"]].copy()
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. By doing is it gives me the following error message: KeyError: "['opcodes'] not in index"

Comment: Something strange is happening with your dataframe where you are creating opcodes. Are you 100% sure that what you are using has the opcodes column within it? @J.D.

Comment: I reloaded all the cells in my jupyter notebook and now it is working fine. Thank you vey much.

Comment: Happy to help :)